# Access global scope from exec statement - restricted python

Tags: python, scope

I realize the question is a bit specific, sorry.

I'm trying to solve a python puzzle where what I input get `exec`'ed. My aim is to store something of arbitrary length in the global name space (e.g, change the variable `target`). You'll see below that my input is limited to `35` chars.

Here's the program:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from sys import modules
modules.clear()
del modules

raw_input2 = raw_input
exception2 = Exception

__builtins__.__dict__.clear()
__builtins__ = None

target = None # change this !

while 1:
    try:
        scope = {'r':0}
        exec 'r = ' + raw_input2()[:35] in scope
        print 'Result:', scope['r']
    except exception2, e:
        print "Error: ", e
```

As said, my point is to store data *somewhere*, since `vars` get reset each loop.

- I know I could use `globals()['target']=xxx`, but the builtins were disabled.
- In theory I could use `global target;target=xxx` but this executes in `scope`, not in the global scope (also I think the `global` keyword must come at the beginning of the anonymous function)
- I know all variables are stored in some `__dict__` object, but the only way I know to write in it is via `globals()['target']=xxx` which is disabled
- I know you can painfully access the super-object with `().__class__.__base__`, but with the limit of `35` characters, it doesn't seem to be the way (this string alone is `21` chars already, you need two more to start with `0;`, so only `11` char remaining to assign something...).

Any ideas ?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to escape the `scope` and get your hands on the real globals. Even if you somehow managed to import `__main__`, you'd only get a copy of it.

Comment: Ok thanks. But if I had access to `globals()` that would be doable? Do you think I can re-import it ?

Comment: No, `globals()` would give you `scope`. It wouldn't help.

Comment: I'm a bit lost. I thought `locals()` would give me the local scope, corresponding to `scope`. So `globals()` is not... "global" ?

Comment: Actually, you can access the globals if you somehow manage to execute this: `import inspect; inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals['target'] = 5`

Comment: `exec cmd in scope` sets `scope` as the global _and_ local scope of any commands in `cmd`.

Comment: That's helpful for my understanding, thanks. Unfortunately I don't have `import` in this puzzle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: write in `__builtins__`.

Example input:

```
1;__builtins__['a']="string1"
Result: 1
1;__builtins__['a']+="string2"
```

... which actually seems very simple since it is right above the variable marked `# change this` in the question. I do not fully understand yet why the `__builtins__` var is passed in the `exec` scope, especially since it should be `None` (and hence not a dictionary), but is assignable like a dictionary.

But it works, tested in python 2.7